# Como usar linhas de indentação no Delphi XE7?

Tags: delphi, dll

Existe um programa, o cnPack que permite fazer isso, e estava usando no Delphi 7, mas, ao trocar a versão do Delphi, precisei baixar novamente e daí veio o problema, ao instalar ele reclama que falta uma DLL (DelForEx21.dll) o problema que não consigo achar essa DLL e toda vez que abre o Delphi ele reclama a falta dela mesmo que eu desinstale o programa.
Alguém sabe como consigo essa DLL?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: DelForEX21.dll não é parte do CnPak. Você deve ter se confundido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo erro ter dado por falta da dll `DelForEx21.dll`, então com relação ao  nome temos o componente DelForExp, que foi integrado a base de código de GExperts em uma versão experimental do GExperts, http://blog.dummzeuch.de/experimental-gexperts-version/, pois oficialmente pelo nome conhecido não integra mais ao GExperts.

Pode ser que atualizando o GExperts seu erro não acontece mais, então tente desinstalar e abrir o XE7, e então reinstalar o GExperts.

Comment: Obrigado. Era isso mesmo.
Descobri que deve ter sido instalado esse outro programa junto e não percebi. Desinstalei tudo e refiz os passos baixando versão mais atualizada e resolveu.

Comment: Jefferson, marca como resolvido (icone de ✓ no lado esquerdo) ;)